# PyCharm numpy - sorting an array doesn't work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I was trying to run some code and sort an array, below is the code.
Online it says that an array can be sorted using this way but when I run this code, the output is None instead of the sorted code, can someone explain why?
In Jupyter Notebook it works fine when I tested it.
Both ways don't work - why is that ?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([3, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3])
arr_sorted = arr.sort()
print(arr_sorted)

# alternative way 
arr_sorted2 = np.ndarray.sort(arr)
    print(arr_sorted2)
```

Additionally I found that this works instead - but I still don't know the why.

```
print(np.sort(arr))
ab = np.sort(arr)
print(ab)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take `sort` as the method of class `ndarray`, it sorts the array in place and returns `None`, but if you use `sort` like a funcion of numpy by calling `np.sort`, then in this case it returns a sorted copy of the array, and the original reamins the same. So it is not a malfunction of numpy in Pycharm

Comment: why does it work though in jupyter then?

Comment: it also outputs **None** in Jupyter

Comment: check the picture i have added on top please @Berger - ah now i see! thanks both

Answer (score 6):

The reason is when you call `sort()` on the array itself, it sorts the array in-place and returns `None`, so `arr_sorted` is `None` too in the first part of your code. Better call the method ins this way:

```
arr.sort()
```

This is also the case for `np.ndarray.sort(arr)`, therefore `arr_sorted2` is also `None`.

But, calling `np.sort(arr)` returns the sorted array as another object, and it should be called in this way:

```
arr = np.sort(arr)
```

The behavior is the same for Jupyter, you may need to restart your notebook and try again to get valid outputs from your code, because the notebook might held the last state of your variables.